# Better global elevation data

Tags: metadata

For my online 3D earth model on guadTree algorithm I need elevation data for all land and oceans.

I recently discovered SRTM 1 Arc-Second Global, but it does not have data for the oceans and the most northern and southern latitudes. I studied the [article](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Global_datasets#SRTM30plus_data_DEM), but I still can not decide. What data are better?

And where better to store this data? In MySQL? If I need to get the elevation of a particular point by lat/long in order to generate an arbitrary terrain pieces.

Comment: Deciding which data are "better" will depend partly on how you intend to use them. For example, if global land and ocean coverage is your most important criterion, then obviously the SRTM data will not suit your needs, and if 1 arc-second resolution is more important to you, then you may not be able to find a data set that covers the entire globe. Different data sets will have different advantages and disadvantages in terms of resolution, coverage, accuracy and consistency, and before anyone can say which data set is better, it needs to be asked: which qualities are most important to you?

Comment: I assume you're familiar with the 1/9-arcsecond data available at: http://viewer.nationalmap.gov/basic/?basemap=b1&category=ned,nedsrc&title=3DEP%20View